# Rails 4 - Font Awesome Icons in Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to

Im trying to figure out how to make a link in my show page.

I want a link to

```
<%= @project.external_link %>.
```

I want to display it as:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-link"></i>' %>
```

I've tried at least 20 variations on combining these two and I can't find a way that works.

Does anyone know how to display a font awesome icon, with a link to a dynamic field?

Comment: Did you check `link_to do` tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to @project.external_link do %>
  <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using :

```
<a href="<%= @project.external_link%>"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
```

Comment: It's always better to do the things in Rails way when you are working in Rails. So `link_to` would always be a best option.